# MongoDB aggregation: How to flatten an object?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document:

```
{
  value: {
   a: 1,
   b: 'yellow',
   c: {'foo': 'baz'}
  }
}
```

How can I transform it to

```
{
   a: 1,
   b: 'yellow',
   c: {'foo': 'baz'}
}
```

Note: I don't want to project each and every field manually. I'm looking for an automatic way to do it

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for $replaceRoot. Try this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iVaAfJ7-CPo).

```
 {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$value"
    }
  }
```

More info in [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/).